# iOS tableview doesnt push view when needed too

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing, nsarray, nsxmlparser

I have a tableview that has a list of xml links that gets parsed using NSXML parser and then pushes to a new view with the parsed results. However, it is acting very strange. The parse operation happens when the user selects the cell, and then using the NSXML delegate method didEndDocument, it notifies the object with the tableview to go ahead and push the new view controller that is populated by the results of the parse. Before pushing to the new view, I check the array with results to make sure it is not empty. If it is, I don't push the new view and just display an alert view. Whenever I select a cell that I know will return a populated array, it thinks the array is empty and doesn't push the view. But then I select the cell again and it pushes to the new view, displaying the proper data. It is not pushing to the new view controller prematurely before the parse operation is done, unless the didEndDocument delegate method is being called pre-maturely. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activity.center = selectedCell.accessoryView.center;

    selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    selectedCell.accessoryView = activity;

    [activity startAnimating];

    departmentName = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    [self performSelector:@selector(parse:) withObject:[[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"] afterDelay:0];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)parse:(NSString *)link {

    NSLog(@"Link = %@", link);

    kxmlParser = [[KMXMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:link delegate:self];
}

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    NSLog(@"Did Start");
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    NSLog(@"Did End");

    NSLog(@"Array = %@", kxmlParser.posts);

    [activity stopAnimating];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];
    MainViewController *main = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];
    [main setDepartmentname:departmentName];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:main animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Does you log of "Parser Did Finish" print when you select a cell that you know returns a populated array?

Comment: It logs the array count 0 when I select it the first time, and for example, 3 the second time I select it. But it's weird, parserDidFinish is ONLY called when didEndDocument in NSXML Parser is called... So I don't get why it is acting pre-mature.